# AngularJS con Karma, Node.js y Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, nodejs, karma-jasmine

Probando AngularJs con Karma, Node.js y Jasmine obtengo este error corriendo scripts/test.bat en consola.

```
Chrome 48.0.2564 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined
```

¿Qué significa?

Estoy usando Angular Seed.

Comment: Que significa es fácil saberlo, y es que en algún lugar del app el module esta como undefined, porque pasa eso es difícil saberlo ya que no das código para darte una solución.

Comment: Hola spideep, Bienvenido a SO en Español, actualmente nos es muy dificil ayudarte con tu problema, ya que no pones código o archivos de configuración de tu proyecto, por favor edita tu pregunta y  agrega toda la información que nos pueda ayudar a encontrar el problema

Answer (score 1):

En algún lugar de tu código hay algo así como

```
expresion.module = algo
```

si `expresion` vale `undefined` el error es el que se muestra. Para encontrarlo se puede presionar el botón debug (en el Chrome) con el debuger abierto (F12) y marcado para que se detenga en las excepciones.

Otra forma de encontrar el error es buscar ".module" dentro del código